# Devise error on auto-generated slim

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, slim-lang

When i use `devise's` edit user registration `slim` file, it gives this error:

```
Started GET "/users/edit" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-04-30 00:28:39 +0530
Processing by Devise::RegistrationsController#edit as HTML
User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 4 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
Rendered devise/registrations/edit.html.slim within layouts/application (5.0ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 9ms

ActionView::Template::Error (Multiple your attributes specified):
temple (0.6.7) lib/temple/html/attribute_merger.rb:15:in `block in on_html_attrs'
temple (0.6.7) lib/temple/html/attribute_merger.rb:12:in `each'
temple (0.6.7) lib/temple/html/attribute_merger.rb:12:in `on_html_attrs'
(eval):7:in `dispatcher'
temple (0.6.7) lib/temple/mixins/dispatcher.rb:49:in `compile'
temple (0.6.7) lib/temple/html/dispatcher.rb:26:in `on_html_tag'
(eval):17:in `dispatcher'
temple (0.6.7) lib/temple/mixins/dispatcher.rb:49:in `compile'
temple (0.6.7) lib/temple/mixins/dispatcher.rb:7:in `block in on_multi'
emple (0.6.7) lib/temple/mixins/dispatcher.rb:7:in `each'
temple (0.6.7) lib/temple/mixins/dispatcher.rb:7:in `on_multi'
(eval):32:in `dispatcher'
temple (0.6.7) lib/temple/mixins/dispatcher.rb:49:in `compile'
temple (0.6.7) lib/temple/html/dispatcher.rb:27:in `on_html_tag'
```

The user Registration slim file is :

```
h2
 | Edit #{resource_name.to_s.humanize}
= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name), html: { method: :put }) do |f|
    = devise_error_messages!
    div
        = f.label :email
        br
        = f.email_field :email, autofocus: true
    - if devise_mapping.confirmable? && resource.pending_reconfirmation?
    div
        | Currently waiting confirmation for: #{resource.unconfirmed_email}
    div
        = f.label :password
        i (leave blank if you dont want to change it)
        br
        = f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off"
    div
        = f.label :password_confirmation
        br
        = f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "off"
    div
        = f.label :current_password
        i (we need your current password to confirm your changes)
        br
        = f.password_field :current_password, autocomplete: "off"
    div= f.submit "Update"
h3 Cancel my account
p
    | Unhappy? #{button_to "Cancel my account", registration_path(resource_name), data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" }, method: :delete}
= link_to "Back", :back
```

How to solve this error?

**Note** : This `slim` file is auto-generated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it.

Error was after this line :

```
- if devise_mapping.confirmable? && resource.pending_reconfirmation?
```

`div's` were not indented, so the if block will not end, hence the error.